# Azure Point to Site - AAD Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openvpn, azure-vpn

I have set up a point to site connection from a VNET to a Windows system. Using Azure VPN Client with AD authentication to establish the connection. How long is the AD token valid after login and is there a way to change it?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the [lifetime of an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties-after-the-retirement) based on Azure AD authentication is about 1 hour,  the token will expire after 1 hour.

If you want to customize the lifetime of the token (increase or decrease), you need to use powershell to [create a token lifetime policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes), and then assign the policy to the service principal to set the token lifetime.